# RANKX showing double numbers and skipping series

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have been trying to rank 2 columns using a calculated column however, i can't seem to make it work properly. I'm new to Power BI so I'm not really sure if I'm missing something. I'm suspecting it has something to do with my filters, but even without the filters, RANKX is still not working properly.

I created a new table

```
rankingYear = 
SUMMARIZE(
    responses,
    responses[Year],    
    responses[Name],
    "Positive", SUM(responses[Positive]),
    "Passive", SUM(responses[Passive]),
    "Negative", SUM(responses[Negative]),
    "Responses", SUM(responses[Responses]),
    "Score", IFERROR(((SUM(responses[Positive])/SUM(responses[Responses]))-(SUM(responses[Negative])/SUM(responses[Responses])))*100,0)
    )
```

Then I transposed it into a Table Visualization, then I added some filters to hide empty **Name**s, **Year** is 2022,and **Responses** must be more than 4

Then I created a Ranker column which I would use for RANKX later:

```
Ranker = 
VAR MaxResponse = MAX(rankingYear[Responses])
VAR Result =            
       (rankingYear[Score] * MaxResponse) + rankingYear[Responses]    
RETURN
    Result
```

And then I created the Rank Column:

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(rankingYear),rankingYear[Ranker],,DESC,Dense)
```

However, it will not show a proper series. It doubles up and skips some numbers:

[image]

I'm adding a link to my sample data here:
[Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DT_bk-mOGe-c-tYUx6N4jAlbfzyF_A2x/view?usp=sharing)

Hoping someone can help me figure this one out. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that in your code fifth parameter is DENSE? Oputput looks like from using SKIP.

Rank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(rankingYear),rankingYear[Ranker],rankingYear[Ranker],DESC,Dense)

Comment: @msta42a - yes I'm using dense

Comment: Edit your question and add some dummy data to reproduce
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @msta42a - Done adding the sample data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you made the measure into a calculated column. As a column, your measure is working great as in it has ranked every row in the table, like you can see if you look into into the data. A calculated column is unaffected by filtering a visual. For your table visuals filters to work, just transform it into a proper measure. For easier working, you can make measure for the RANKX expression, for example:

```
Ranker_Sum = SUM('Sample Data'[Ranker])
```

And you are all set for:

```
Rank as a measure = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Sample Data'); [Ranker_Sum];;DESC;Dense)
```

It should work like this in a table with filters.